# About Interval, World Line and 4-Velocity Vector

Tags: general-relativity

I am confused by a few concepts. Can you check if my understand is correct?

1) World line is locus of a particle as a function of 4-coordinate. Its length is the interval.

2) Although we can draw world line of a 2D spatial coordinate in our real space (assign time to the 3rd dimension of our real space), the length of the world line is still the interval, not the length we see in our real space.

3) 4-vector is always tangential to world line, right? And if I draw the world line like in the case of 2), is it still tangential to the line we can see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is true
2. Correct, although in this example 'our real space' would mean a 2D space
3. The 4-velocity is indeed tangent to the world line.

Comment: Thank you! But for 2., I was trying to say, if we were studying the motion of a particle which is limited to a 2-D space + time, then we can draw its world line in our "real 3D space" (one axis will be the time). And we see the world line. However, the length of the world line is still the interval, not the length of the line I drew in my "real 3D space". Is that right?

Comment: You are right! It would be the interval

Answer (score 3):

I think 3) should be explained a bit. The "length" you measure in GR is with respect to the Lorentz metric of the spacetime manifold. So 1) and 2) depend on this metric, which is decidedly not the metric of the space we draw the curve in. For instance, null curves have nonzero length when we draw them, but the length wrt. the Lorentz metric is zero.

Now, the notion of being "tangent" to a curve has nothing to do with the metric, it depends only on the smooth structure of the manifold. That is to say, we could have a notion of a vector being tangent (but not orthogonal!) to a curve without a metric present.